# Why is the FileMode.Create being used in another process?

Tags: c#, .net, process, filestream

So I am currently developing a simple application that will take a screenshot of my desktop and then I can send it quickly though an email to a friend or family.

Here is the thing though..
When i press the Inilizalize button it runs through these methods..

```
        screenshot();
        setImage();
        saveScreenshot();
        sendScreenImage();
```

It takes a screenshot > sets the screenshot as the source in a image container > saves whats in the image container > sends it to who ever I want to send it to. 
 Simple right?

It all works great, Lets say I just run through taking the picture and saving it, it can replace (overwrite) the old one everytime I press 
 screenshot > set image > save screenshot 
 but as soon as I send it (add the sendScreenImage(); method) I cant overwrite the old image anymore because it says that that the process is being used

> Error message: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

and its always throwing me that error in the same place which would be at this line

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
```

in saveScreenshot();

### --QUESTION--

#### Whats using the process? And do I need to multithread the thing thats using the process or can I just cancel it?

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using WPFCSharpWebCam;

namespace WebcamApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        #region methods
        private void initializeToolBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            screenshot();
            setImage();
            saveScreenshot();
            sendScreenImage();
        }
        private void screenshot()
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}");
        }

        private void setImage()
        {
            System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
            var clipboardImage = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
            image.Source = clipboardImage;
        }


        private void saveScreenshot()
        {
            try
            {
                string path;
                path = "%AppData%\\image.png"; // collection of paths
                path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)image.Source));
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Replaced the old screenshot");
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(" saveScreenshot() went wrong " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void sendScreenImage()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
                var clipboardImage = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
                image.Source = clipboardImage;

                string path;
                path = "%AppData%\\image.png"; // collection of paths
                path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);


                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress(emailfromTextbox.Text, "Screenshot Image");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTextbox.Text));
                msg.Subject = "SCreenshot Image";
                msg.Body = clipboardImage.ToString();
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");

                //create the LinkedResource(embedded image)
                LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path);
                logo.ContentId = "image.png";
                //add the LinkedResource to the appropriate view

                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

                msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailTextbox.Text, emailpasswordTextbox.Text);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(msg);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "GMAIL Error" + ex.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: `clipboardImage.ToString()` will not do anything useful.

Comment: I know, I need to clean up the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinkedResource` owns a file stream to read the attachment.

You need to dispose that in a `using` block after you send the email.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Im gonna try logo.Dispose();

Comment: @GooberS.Johnsson: The same way you already use `using()` statements everywhere else.

Comment: So after I send the email i need to create a using statement for `LinkedResource` and the logo?

Comment: No; you need to wrap the code that uses it in a `using` statement.  Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Oh so basically the whole sendScreenImage() method?